# Decimal Qty increment not working

Tags: magento2, product, qty, qty-increment

I am not able to set qty increments as decimal (example 0.5) for product.
can anyone help me on that.

Comment: In which page are you trying to set qty decimal increment?

Comment: Which magento version are you using? and please share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

To use decimal Qty your setting should be like below.

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

this Option in Decimal Points **[For ex 0.25]** or anything minimum quantity you want to add into cart.

**Note :** *if you are working with tire pricing then decimal quantity not working because it is default magento bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12914*

I hope it helps!